# show tinymce contents in a div with flexible though maximum height

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

When using an editor like tinymce, how could i limit the height of the text a user enters so it doesn't use more space on the webpage than i want it to?

There are 2 things that i want some advise on:

**In the editor:**
The user enters text in a tinymce editor, he could set a text to font-size say 80px which would use up more space than a normal letter. So it's not the amount of text that i care about it's the height of the total.

**In the webpage:**
 I don't want to give them more than say 200px worth of text on the page. But if they enter just 1 line of text with a small font-size i don't want to show a 200px space. So the height has to be flexible but with a maximum.

I know this isn't exact science but the goal here is to prevent the user from messing up the page.

Comment: good question. I haven't got answer but if you don't have another answer, display tinymce with an "overflow: hidden" and the maximum desired height. The user will automatically know what the maximum height (because he will not see its text after that height) and use a classic div to display the content with a css max-height property and overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

To solve a similar issue i wrote the following function (placed inside an own tinymce plugin). You will need to add a variable for the maximum case and maybe tweak it a bit, but i hope this code will put you into the right direction

```
    // this function will adjust the editors iframe height to fit in the editors content perfectly
    resizeIframe: function(editor) {
        var frameid = frameid ? frameid :editor.id+'_ifr';
        var currentfr=document.getElementById(frameid);

        if (currentfr && !window.opera){
            currentfr.style.display="block";
            if (currentfr.contentDocument && currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight) { //ns6 syntax
                currentfr.height = currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 26;
            }
            else if (currentfr.Document && currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight) { //ie5+ syntax
                    currentfr.height = currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight;
            }
            styles = currentfr.getAttribute('style').split(';');
            for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
                if ( styles[i].search('height:') ==1 ){
                    styles.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            };
            currentfr.setAttribute('style', styles.join(';'));
        }
    },
```